# Could you recommend some classic textbooks on ordinary/partial differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation

I love R. Courant and F. John's *Introduction to Calculus and Analysis* because of its wide coverage, precise description and friendly written style.

Are there any classic textbooks like it on ODE/PDE?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you like the writing style of Courant and John... for PDEs there are of course F. John's *Partial Differential Equations*, and also Courant and Hilbert's *Methods of Mathematical Physics*.

Answer (score 2):

Good books on ODE would be:

1) Ordinary Differential Equations by Morris Tenenbaum and Harry Pollard

2) Differential Equations by George F. Simmons

3) Ordinary Differential Equations by E.Coddington

For PDE, I request you to take a look at this link: http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=175382

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following references:

$(1)\quad $ "Differential Equations" by Shepley L. Ross

$(2)\quad $ "Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes " by George Simmons

$(3)\quad $ "Elements of partial differential equations" by Ian Sneddon

$(4)\quad $ "Differential Equations: Theory, Technique, and Practice" by George F. Simmons and Steven G. Krantz

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of Bentley and Cooke's [Linear Algebra with Differential Equations](http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=1174162092&searchurl=an%3Dbentley%2Band%2Bcooke%26sts%3Dt%26x%3D82%26y%3D18). It was published in the early 70's, it is black and white (i.e. not flashy), and has excellent references throughout the text (such as a footnote pointing to [Kamke](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/082840044X)).

Furthermore, the topics of differential equations and linear algebra are introduced side by side at the introductory level.  I think this is an ideal text for the beginning engineering student that holds him or herself to learning a bit more mathematics than their peers.

Comment: As far as a recognized classic, I guess there is always [Boyce and DiPrima](http://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Differential-Equations-Boundary-Problems/dp/B000H5BEDK/ref=sr_1_33?s=STORE&ie=UTF8&qid=1282797689&sr=1-33) - although it is now in its 427th edition for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it would be considered a classic or not, but I absolutely love [Differential Equations with Boundary-Value Problems](https://books.google.com/books?id=MSbMZCWX2OQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=differential+equations+with+boundary-value+problems&source=bl&ots=-uLwOGzUzB&sig=s5kdyM3Sq0txRfdt9VeIc-XmiKI&hl=en&ei=I352TIvBNoK8lQe12IjsCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&sqi=2#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Dennis G. Zill and Michael R. Cullen.  I feel as though the definitions are written and explained in such a way, that if one was not a mathematician, they could still grasp a basic understanding of many differential equations concepts.  I am not familiar with many other elementary differential equations textbooks, but liked that this text goes into some details regarding [Fourier series](https://planetmath.org/FourierSineAndCosineSeries), [integrals](https://planetmath.org/ApproximatingFourierIntegralsWithDiscreteFourierTransforms), and [transforms](https://planetmath.org/FourierTransform), Legendre series, Bessel functions, and the [Sturm-Louiville problem](https://planetmath.org/EigenvalueProblem).

I still use this text as a reference for some of my graduate level ODE issues, as it is more comprehensible than most graduate level Diff-EQ texts. I also use it quite frequently when tutoring students in undergraduate level differential equations, as it contains a myriad of detailed examples and worked problems as well as a variety of real-world applications.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not sure if it exactly meets your criteria, my favorite PDE book is [*Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction* by Walter A. Strauss](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470054565).