# History of ODE and PDE reference request

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, math-history

Is there any reference (book or articles) which made the history (up to the modern times) and the conceptual development of Ordinary Differential Equations and Partial Differential Equations? It will be great if it will be mentioned the key ideas and people of the past, the problems which are to be solved nowadays and the principal directions of the present research in these fields.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Related: [Book recommendation on the history of PDE/ODE?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3623), Found by looking at posts tagged [math-history+differential-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-history+differential-equations).

Comment: The question was also posted on MO: [History of ODE and PDE reference request](https://mathoverflow.net/q/308880). (As a side note, I think that [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) gives very reasonable advice on [meta-tag:cross-posting]).