# ODE book recommendation

Tags: reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations

I have just completed my first year study and know elementary analysis and a little bit functional analysis.
I found that most of the ODE books just focus on calculation but no substantial explanation of theorems.Can someone suggest some ODE books which are from a more theoretical point of view?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34233/ode-introduction-textbook

Comment: Its not an ODE book, and it be heavy going at an early stage, but I like the (brief) treatment of ODEs in Kantorovich & Akilov's "Functional Analysis". In particular, it provides a fixed-point scheme (as in Picard) that is useful for showing continuity of solutions with respect to parameters.

Comment: [The Qualitative Theory of Ordinary Differential Equations](https://www.amazon.com/Qualitative-Theory-Ordinary-Differential-Equations/dp/0486658465) by Brauer and Nohel is worth a look.

Answer (score 9):

A classical theoretical book on ODE is [Hartman](http://books.google.com/books/about/Ordinary_Differential_Equations.html?id=CENAPMUEpfoC).

A very good book, and slightly less demanding than Hartman is [Hale's book](http://books.google.com/books/about/Ordinary_differential_equations.html?id=2jOxAAAAIAAJ)

A geometric picture of differential equations is given in two Arnold's books: [one](http://books.google.com/books?id=JUoyqlW7PZgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=inauthor%3a%22Vladimir+Igorevich+Arnol%CA%B9d%22&source=bl&ots=rbLXCPSoaX&sig=BOxf-ZZmValzvC0ZBtHJjHPbW-Q&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JdwSUOimJ-j20gHryICYCQ&ved=0CFoQ6AEwBzgK#v=onepage&q&f=false) and [two](http://books.google.com/books?id=i-WJHniwLVwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=inauthor%3a%22Vladimir+Igorevich+Arnol%CA%B9d%22&source=bl&ots=zmWKJTDTvB&sig=wFEoNQJ4SjM4dZhDe0fjo2ClKCs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JdwSUOimJ-j20gHryICYCQ&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q&f=false)

ODE from a dynamical system theory point of view are presented in [Wiggins' book](http://books.google.com/books?id=GYcOfuZDOKMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=wiggins+dynamical&source=bl&ots=bF_2mG7Ic2&sig=-rxGhMesSa237AUAOIjG-S7C-xc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=edwSUPL7Kayw0AGnnIDICQ&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=wiggins%20dynamical&f=false)

**Update:** Have no idea how, but I read that the question was about a *second* theoretical ODE course. For the first course in ODE none of the books that I mentioned (except Arnold's one) suits.

The best first theoretical book on ODE is, for my taste, is [Hirsch and Smale](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123495504).

Comment: Hartman is great for references, but I would kill myself if I had to use it for self-study as my first ODE course. Arnold's books make excellent reading.

Comment: @LeonidKovalev Ups. Somehow I understood that OP asked about a _second_ course in differential equations. I update my post.

Answer (score 2):

You might try [Birkhoff and Rota](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=YBjEQgAACAAJ) or [Lefschetz](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=Ey8hPQAACAAJ) or [Nemytskii and Stepanov](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=3-mpZDFifoYC).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one also...

'Differential Equations Theory, Technique and Practice' by G. F. Simmons & S. G. Krantz (McGraw Hill Higher Education)

Answer (score 0):

Try lecture notes by [Alexander Grigorian](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Egrigor/odelec2009.pdf) and [Peter Philip](https://www.math.lmu.de/%7Ephilip/publications/lectureNotes/philipPeter_ODE.pdf). These are the most rigorous texts on ODE I have read.